# Show Two custom Post type and their posts on category page

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, customization, custom-taxonomy, query

I have Two Custom Post Types "Article " & "News" and they both use same categories
like [ audit , income , tax] . I want when i open audit category page then the post showsn like below: [image]

the code i already tried on archieve.php but isnt working:

```
<?php

    $cats = get_the_category();
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'articles',
        'post__not_in' => array( get_the_ID() ),
        'posts_per_page' => 5,
        'cat'     => $cats[0]->term_id,
        'meta_query' => array(
                    array(
                    'key' => 'recommended_article',
                    'value' => '1',
                    'compare' => '=='
                        )
                    )
    );
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );

?>  

<?php if( $query->have_posts() ) : while( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>   

<!--HTML-->

<?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its Done Thank U so much Everyone Who Answered!

```
<?php
/*
 * dglib_breadcrumbs_section_template - hook
 *
 * @hooked - dglib_breadcrumbs_section_callback - 10
 *
 * @since 1.0.6
 */

do_action( 'dglib_breadcrumbs_section_template' );
?>
    <div id="primary" class="content-area">
        <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">


<header class="page-header">
                <?php
                    the_archive_title( '<h1 class="page-title">', '</h1>' );
                    the_archive_description( '<div class="archive-description">', '</div>' );

                ?>
            </header>
<div class="row">
                <?php

$category = get_queried_object();

        // news
        $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'news',
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'cat'     =>  $category->term_id,
);

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args ); 
?>
<?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
            <!-- .page-header -->

<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
            <div class="panel panel-default"> 
            <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="sub_header">News</h3>
        </div>
        <ul style="padding-left: 25px; padding-top:15px;list-style: disc; line-height:23px">
<?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
<?php the_title( '<li class="entry-title"><a href="' . esc_url( get_permalink() ) . '" rel="bookmark">', '</a></li>' ); ?>

<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
<?php endwhile;  ?>
</ul>
</div>
</div>

<?php else: ?>
<p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
<?php endif;  ?>
<?php



        // articles
        $args1 = array(
    'post_type' => 'articles',
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'cat'     =>  $category->term_id,
);

$the_query1 = new WP_Query( $args1 ); 
?>
<?php if ( $the_query1->have_posts() ) : ?>
            <!-- .page-header -->

<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
            <div class="panel panel-default"> 
            <div class="panel-heading">
    <h3 class="sub_header">Articles</h3>
        </div>
        <ul style="padding-left: 25px; padding-top:15px;list-style: disc; line-height:23px">
<?php while ( $the_query1->have_posts() ) : $the_query1->the_post(); ?>
<?php the_title( '<li class="entry-title"><a href="' . esc_url( get_permalink() ) . '" rel="bookmark">', '</a></li>' ); ?>

<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
<?php endwhile;  ?>
</ul>
</div>
</div>

<?php else: ?>
<p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
<?php endif;  ?>
</div>
        </main><!-- #main -->
    </div><!-- #primary -->
<?php
get_sidebar();
get_footer();
```

Answer (score 1):

First, I would recommend making this change in Category.php file, as archive.php is affecting tags as well as other archives according to [Wordpress Theme Hierarchy](https://wphierarchy.com/) file system.

Try adding the two queries like next:

```
$cats = get_the_category();
    $cat_id = $cats[0]->term_id;


        // news
        $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'news',
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'cat'     => $cat_id,
);
$query = new WP_Query($args);

if($query->have_posts() ) : 
    while( $query->have_posts() ) :
        $query->the_post();
    endwhile; 
endif; 

wp_reset_postdata(); 

    // articles
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'articles',
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'cat'     => $cat_id,
);
$query = new WP_Query($args);

if($query->have_posts() ) : 
    while( $query->have_posts() ) :
        $query->the_post();
    endwhile; 
endif; 

wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: Tried !! its showing Blank Page

Comment: Please set WP_DEBUG to true in your wp-config.php file and refresh the page to get the errors and write them here :)

Answer (score 1):

Create `taxonomy-categories.php` or In your `archive.php` add below code to get post of `article` and `news` post type for current category. I assume that your taxonomy for both post type is `categories`. change `categories` with your taxonomy and `post_type` with your post types for news and article from below code.

```
 # Article 
 $articleargs = array(
        'post_type' => 'article',
        'posts_per_page' => 5,
        'tax_query' => array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'categories',
                'field'    => 'name',
                'terms'    => get_queried_object()
            )
        ),
    );
    $articlequery = new WP_Query( $articleargs );

     if( $articlequery->have_posts() ) : 
        echo "<h2>Articles</h2>";
        echo "<ul>";
        while( $articlequery->have_posts() ) : $articlequery->the_post();   
            echo "<li>".get_the_title()."</li>";
         endwhile; 
         echo "</ul>";
    endif; 
    wp_reset_postdata(); 

    # news
    $newsargs = array(
        'post_type' => 'news',
        'posts_per_page' => 5,
        'tax_query' => array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'categories',
                'field'    => 'name',
                'terms'    => get_queried_object()
            )
        ),
    );
    $newsquery = new WP_Query( $newsargs );

     if( $newsquery->have_posts() ) : 
        echo "<h2>News</h2>";
        echo "<ul>";
        while( $newsquery->have_posts() ) : $newsquery->the_post();   
            echo "<li>".get_the_title()."</li>";
         endwhile; 
         echo "</ul>";
    endif; 
    wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: Thank You this is a Correct Answer

Answer (score 1):

The [`get_the_category()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_category/) function retrieves the categories assigned to the first post from the loop, and that's not what you mean.
I assume that `audit`, `income`, `tax`, etc. are built-in categories, not custom taxonomy (in this case you need to replace `cat` parameter of `WP_Query` to `tax_query`).

Create `category.php` file if it doesn't exist by copying `archive.php`. This way the template will be used only on the category page.

ID of the **currently viewed** category you can get with [`get_queried_object_id()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_queried_object_id/). You don't have to check type of the queried object in the `category.php` file, it will always be correct. Having a category ID, you insert them into the query parameters and you only receive posts belonging to it.

If you intend to apply the template only to selected categories (audit, income, tax) instead of all use the [`{$type}_template`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/type_template/) filter.

```
//
// ge ID of the  current category
$cat_id = get_queried_object_id();

//
// get 'news' posts from current category 
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'news',
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'cat'       => (int)$cat_id,  // <==
    //'meta_query' => array(
    //    array(
    //        'key' => 'recommended_article',
    //        'value' => '1',
    //        'compare' => '=',    // <== 
    //    )
    )
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
//
// display posts
// 
wp_reset_postdata();


//
// get 'articles' posts from current category 
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'articles',   // <==
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'cat'       => (int)$cat_id,
    //'meta_query' => array(
    //    array(
    //        'key' => 'recommended_article',
    //        'value' => '1',
    //        'compare' => '=',
    //    )
    )
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
//
// ...
// 
wp_reset_postdata();
```